# Как сделать сноску?

Tags: поддержка

Как сделать сноску, по нажатию на которую будет скроллиться к её тексту в конец сообщения.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как написали в [ответе на Метамете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes)

> Сноски не нужны. Тут вам не википедия. Если очень хочется для выделения используй `<sup>` или `<sub>`.

Comment: ммммм.... суууупп..... Гомер одобряет)))